# Proper way to set a function's default parameter to a boolean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a function `read()` that takes as a boolean paramater. If  `false` is passed in - `read(false)` - it shouldn't run a block of code. It works with the three variations below, but I'm not sure the difference between them or if it matters?

But I don't understand the difference between the variations.

All these three variations work.

```
this.first_time_here = first_time_here !== false;
var first_time_here = first_time_here !== false;
var first_time_here = first_time_here || false;
```

**read function**

```
   function read (first_time_here) {

            var first_time_here = first_time_here !== false;

            // check to see what the function thinks first_time_here is
            console.log("first time here is:  " + first_time_here);
            if (typeof first_time_here === 'boolean') {
            console.log('Yes, I am a boolean');
            }

            if (first_time_here) {
                   // do something if true

         };
    };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're expecting falsey values, use `typeof`:

```
var x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : false;
```

Otherwise, if you do this:

```
var x = x || true;
```

And pass in `false`, the value of `x` will be `true`.

Comment: Sweet and clear. Thanks for the added version. I'll use that just to have a more robust API.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the concept automatic conversion in Javascript, the `undefined` value convert to `false`. So three lines are similar to ensure the variable `first_time_here` is `false`, not `undefined`.

if `first_time_here` is `undefined`:

```
first_time_here = undedined !== false -> first_time_here = false != false
-> first_time_here = false;
```

And:

```
first_time_here = undedined || false -> first_time_here = false || false
-> first_time_here = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Cuong! Your answer helped too. I chose the answer by @Blender because he provided another option I hadn't considered. ;D